# Connection between client and server doesn't end

Tags: java, tcp

I have a Java server. Clients connect to server via TCP. Here is the case for my problem:
1- 2 clients connect to server(client a & client b)
2- clients communicate with server
3- "client a" disconnects from internet
4- The socket connection of client a doesn't disconnects
5- when "client a" connects to the internet again, "client a" can send messages to the server without connecting to the server.

I expect the connection between server and "client a" ends when "client a" disconnects from internet.

Do you have any opinions about this?

Comment: What exactly does this mean: "when "client a" connects to the internet again, "client a" can send messages to the server without connecting to the server."

Comment: First of all client disconnects from the internet then it connects to the internet again. After client connected to the internet, no new socket is open between client and server. It behaves like the old socket connection is not closed (and i think actually it is not closed). Therefore client can send messages to the server as it never disconnected from server. Is it clear?

Comment: Yes, that's clear. So why is that a problem? The original connection never broke, nor did anyone take any action to break it. If you want to detect disconnection and respond by breaking a connection, even when that connection could survive the disconnection, you can do that. But that's not what most people want and so it's not the default behavior. Code what you want.

Comment: This is problem, because there are numerous clients connected to server and i have to inform other clients if any client disconnects

Comment: Then you need to write some code to implement client disconnect detection. Are you implementing your own protocol or is this a documented protocol? Does it specify how to detect client disconnection? For example, see [RFC1459 section 4.6.2](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1459#section-4.6.2) to see how IRC does it.

Comment: I'm implementing the server based on TCP, i'm not using any other documented protocol. Therefore, this leads me to the solution that i need to implement sth like IRC does and ping the clients based on some conditions or ping them in specified intervals. However, this solution will result an extra overhead in network.

Comment: If detecting a disconnection is a requirement, then you have to try to use the connection to tell if it has disconnected. There is no other way. However, you should document your protocol. Trust me, it will save you many headaches. (Including this one. You had no idea how client disconnection would be detected because you never documented the protocol.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well having opinions and having solutions are two different things :-)

I would recommend adding a keepalive time out to your connection on the server side. Send a keep alive every (few seconds? few minutes?) and if there isn't a keepalive response, kill the connection on the server side.

Comment: Yeap you are right, actually i need solutions (: I want to clearify something with your answer. You tell me to implement sth in the server side to send a keep alive request every few seconds and if there is no response to this request, this means the client is not connected to server anymore. right? This is some kind of pinging the client from server. Right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. If you don't get a response, kill it.

Answer (score 0):

When a machine disconnects from the Internet, it can't send any data over the Internet. That includes sending the packets necessary to close or abort a connection. So there is no way the client can close the connection if it gets disconnected. If this needs to be done, the server has to do it. If you need this ability, the application protocol has to provide it.